# how to use await instead of then in promise?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, promise

How to correctly resolve a Promise.all(...), I'm trying that after resolving the promise which generates a set of asynchronous requests (which are simple database queries in supabase-pg SQL) I'm iterating the result in a forEach , to make a new request with each of the results of the iterations.

But, try to save the result that it brings me in a new array, which prints fine in the console, but in the response that doesn't work. It comes empty, I understand that it is sending me the response before the promise is finished resolving, but I don't understand why.

In an answer to a previous question I was told to use await before the then, but I didn't quite understand how to do it.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
export const getReportMonthly = async(req: Request & any, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {

      let usersxData: UsersxModalidadxRolxJob[] = [];
      let data_monthly: HoursActivityWeeklySummary[] = [];
      let attendance_schedule: AttendanceSchedule[] = [];
      let time_off_request: TimeOffRequestRpc[] = [];
      let configs: IndicatorConfigs[] = [];

      const supabaseService = new SupabaseService();

      const promises = [
        supabaseService.getSummaryWeekRpcWihoutFreelancers(req.query.fecha_inicio, req.query.fecha_final).then(dataFromDB => {
          data_monthly = dataFromDB as any;
        }),
        supabaseService.getUsersEntity(res).then(dataFromDB => {
          usersxData = dataFromDB as any;
        }),
        supabaseService.getAttendaceScheduleRpc(req.query.fecha_inicio, req.query.fecha_final).then(dataFromDB => {
          attendance_schedule = dataFromDB as any;
        }),
        supabaseService.getTimeOffRequestRpc(req.query.fecha_inicio, req.query.fecha_final).then(dataFromDB => {
          time_off_request = dataFromDB as any;
        }),
        supabaseService.getConfigs(res).then(dataFromDB => {
          configs = dataFromDB;
        }),

      ];

      let attendanceInMonthly = new Array();
      await Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        attendance_schedule.forEach(element => {
          let start_date = element.date_start.toString();
          let end_date = element.date_end.toString();

          supabaseService.getTrackedByDateAndIDArray(start_date, end_date).then(item => {
            console.log(item);
            attendanceInMonthly.push(item);
          });
        });
      })

      res.json(attendanceInMonthly)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
        title: 'API-CIT Error',
        message: 'Internal server error'
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you launch a few requests, among which one (`getAttendaceScheduleRpc`, which assigns `attendance_schedule`) is used to launch some extra requests again, and you need to wait for all of these (including the extra requests) before returning?

In that case, the immediate issue is that you perform your extra requests in "subqueries", but you do not wait for them.

A very simple solution would be to properly separate those 2 steps, somehow like in DerHerrGammler's answer, but using `attendance_schedule` instead of `resolvedPromises` as input for the 2nd step:

```js
let attendanceInMonthly = new Array();
await Promise.all(promises);

await Promise.all(attendance_schedule.map(async (element) => {
  let start_date = element.date_start.toString();
  let end_date = element.date_end.toString();

  const item = await supabaseService.getTrackedByDateAndIDArray(start_date, end_date);

  console.log(item);
  attendanceInMonthly.push(item);
});

res.json(attendanceInMonthly);
```

---

If you are really looking to fine tune your performance, you could take advantage of the fact that your extra requests depend *only* on the result of *one* of your initial requests (`getAttendaceScheduleRpc`), so you could launch them as soon as the latter is fullfilled, instead of waiting for *all* the promises of the 1st step:

```js
let attendance_schedule: AttendanceSchedule[] = [];
let attendanceInMonthly = new Array();

const promises = [
  supabaseService.getAttendaceScheduleRpc(req.query.fecha_inicio, req.query.fecha_final).then(dataFromDB => {
    attendance_schedule = dataFromDB as any;

    // Immediately launch your extra (2nd step) requests, without waiting for other 1st step requests
    // Make sure to return when all new extra requests are done, or a Promise
    // that fullfills when so.
    return Promise.all(attendance_schedule.map(async (element) => {
      let start_date = element.date_start.toString();
      let end_date = element.date_end.toString();

      const item = await supabaseService.getTrackedByDateAndIDArray(start_date, end_date);

      console.log(item);
      attendanceInMonthly.push(item);
    });
  }),
  // etc. for the rest of 1st step requests
];

await Promise.all(promises);

res.json(attendanceInMonthly);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me, I needed a concept, I thought that if I had different promises for them to unfold, I was doing it wrong. That it was going to fall into some kind of nested code, but now I understand that it is not. From @ghybs's answer, use the second option where I optimize the code so that after bringing attendance_schedule and only if the array is not empty, it returns the new attendanceInMonthly list. Regards!

Answer (score 2):

If you await a promise you could write the return of this in a variable and work with this normaly.
So instead of your current code you could use the following changed code:

```
export const getReportMonthly = async(req: Request & any, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {

      let usersxData: UsersxModalidadxRolxJob[] = [];
      let data_monthly: HoursActivityWeeklySummary[] = [];
      let attendance_schedule: AttendanceSchedule[] = [];
      let time_off_request: TimeOffRequestRpc[] = [];
      let configs: IndicatorConfigs[] = [];

      const supabaseService = new SupabaseService();

      const promises = [
        supabaseService.getSummaryWeekRpcWihoutFreelancers(req.query.fecha_inicio, req.query.fecha_final).then(dataFromDB => {
          data_monthly = dataFromDB as any;
        }),
        supabaseService.getUsersEntity(res).then(dataFromDB => {
          usersxData = dataFromDB as any;
        }),
        supabaseService.getAttendaceScheduleRpc(req.query.fecha_inicio, req.query.fecha_final).then(dataFromDB => {
          attendance_schedule = dataFromDB as any;
        }),
        supabaseService.getTimeOffRequestRpc(req.query.fecha_inicio, req.query.fecha_final).then(dataFromDB => {
          time_off_request = dataFromDB as any;
        }),
        supabaseService.getConfigs(res).then(dataFromDB => {
          configs = dataFromDB;
        }),

      ];

      const resolvedPromises = await Promise.all(promises)
      const attendanceInMonthly = await Promise.all(
          resolvedPromises.map(
              async (element) => {
                  let start_date = element.date_start.toString();
                  let end_date = element.date_end.toString();
                  return supabaseService.getTrackedByDateAndIDArray(start_date, end_date)
              }
          )
      )

      console.log(attendanceInMonthly) // this should be your finaly resolved promise

      res.json(attendanceInMonthly)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
        title: 'API-CIT Error',
        message: 'Internal server error'
      });
    }
```

Something like this should your code looks like. I am not sure if this solves exactly your code because your code has  some syntax errors wich you have to solve for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, what confuses me is that you declare 'const attendanceInMonthly' and there you map the set of requests that you have resolved with Promise.all 'resolvedPromises.map' but how do you know that you are actually mapping on the object that you are needing? In this use case it's "attendance_schedule", because, I mean, 'resolvedPromises' is the array of all the requests, of all the data

Comment: but I don't need to map all the data, I need to resolve the requests and once I have access to them individually, to be able to do what I need, which in this case is the mapping to be able to make a request per iteration

Comment: ah then i read your code wrong. i thought that the `attendance_schedule` is the return of the promise. you never assigned attendance_schedule. Then in this case is the problem, that you  made a foreach an in this use use a async request. if u want to keep your structure you can just change it to a map wrap it in a awaited Promise.all and return the request in the map just like my code